# Print top-level parent with all childrens from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, data-structures

We have to print top-level parents with all direct and indirect children. There can be multiple top-level parents. But each child will have only 1 top-level parent only. The input and output format is given below. The output should be an array of objects where each object should have an id and a list of all children. **-1 indicates top-level parent and the child may or may not exist in the input(example: 6 in below input)**.

**INPUT:**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [2, 3],
    parent: -1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [4, 5],
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    children: [],
    parent: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    children: [6],
    parent: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    children: [8, 9],
    parent: -1,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    children: [],
    parent: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    children: [],
    parent: 7,
  },
];
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    children: [8, 9],
  },
];
```

The solution I tried:

```
function formatData(data) {
  const map = {};
  for (let datum of data) {
    let parentId = datum.parent === -1 ? datum.id : datum.parent;
    if (parentId in map) {
      map[parentId].push(datum.id, ...datum.children);
    } else {
      map[parentId] = [];
      map[parentId].push(...datum.children);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, not a typo, the child may or may not exist in the input. I'll update the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I saw the unaccept, is there a situation for which my suggested code isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [2, 3],
    parent: -1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [4, 5],
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    children: [],
    parent: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    children: [6],
    parent: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    children: [8, 9],
    parent: -1,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    children: [],
    parent: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    children: [],
    parent: 7,
  },
];

function formatData(data) {
  const tmpTree = [...data];

  tmpTree.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.parent === -1) return;

    const parent = tmpTree.find((p) => p.id === d.parent);

    if (parent.childNodes) {
      parent.childNodes.push(d);
    } else {
      parent.childNodes = [d];
    }
  });

  const tree = tmpTree.filter((d) => d.parent === -1);

  function getChildren(node) {
    const children = [...node.children];

    if (node.parent !== -1) {
      children.push(node.id);
    }

    if (node.childNodes) {
      children.push(...node.childNodes.flatMap(getChildren));
    }

    return [...new Set(children)];
  }

  const final = tree.map((node) => {
    const children = getChildren(node);

    return {
      id: node.id,
      children,
    };
  });

  return final;
}

console.log(formatData(input));
```

It does alter the items in the input, but you can rework it to avoid that if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Every item has either a parent of `-1` (the root to use) or the ID of a parent that's been iterated over already. Use that to iterate over the items and create a Set of each child ID found for each root element. Because some of the objects don't have a `parent` matching the root ID that's needed, cache each object's ID with its root parent when iterated over the first time, so that objects coming later can look it up easily.

```js
const data=[{id:1,children:[2,3],parent:-1},{id:2,children:[4,5],parent:1},{id:3,children:[4,5],parent:1},{id:4,children:[],parent:2},{id:5,children:[6],parent:2},{id:7,children:[8,9],parent:-1},{id:8,children:[],parent:7},{id:9,children:[],parent:7}];

function formatData(data) {
  const rootParentsById = {};
  const outputById = {};
  for (const obj of data) {
    if (obj.parent === -1) {
      outputById[obj.id] = new Set(obj.children);
    } else {
      const parentId = rootParentsById[obj.parent] ?? obj.parent;
      rootParentsById[obj.id] = parentId;
      outputById[parentId].add(obj.id);
      for (const child of obj.children) {
        outputById[parentId].add(child);
      }
    }
  }
  return Object.entries(outputById).map(
    ([id, childrenIdSet]) => ({
      id,
      children: [...childrenIdSet]
    })
  );
}
console.log(formatData(data));
```